# _splashBloc..add(SplashStartEvent() gives error 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true."

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

```
return BlocProvider<SplashBloc>(
      create: (context) => _splashBloc..add(SplashStartEvent()),
      child: BlocBuilder<SplashBloc, SplashState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              body: Center(
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/logo_white.png',
                  height: 0.8.sh,
                  width: 1.sw,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

.. usage gives following error, previously it's working fine.

"'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4313 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true."